# GitHub API wrapper using Graphql(v4) only?

Tags: graphql, github-api

tl;dr - can you write a complete GitHub API wrapper without using v3?

I'm working on creating a wrapper for the GitHub API to use in my project.
I need to be able to upload/download multiple files.
get full folder tree.
get info by commits.

all of this is pretty straight forward in the REST API (v3) (already implemented)
but in the GraphQl API, I can't find anything related to creating blobs or anything that resembles pushing a file.